# Infragistics UltraLabel ForeColor

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics

With the available R, G & B values, how do I set the `ForeColor` property of an `UltraLabel`? I've tried the following:

```
UltraLabel lbl = new UltraLabel();
lbl.Text = "Some text";
lbl.Appearance.ForeColor.R = 255; // ERROR: Property or indexer 'System.Drawing.Color.R' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
lbl.Appearance.ForeColor.G = 255; // ERROR: Property or indexer 'System.Drawing.Color.G' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
lbl.Appearance.ForeColor.B = 255; // ERROR: Property or indexer 'System.Drawing.Color.B' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

Any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe try:

```
lbl.Appearance.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lbl.Appearance.ForeColor = new Color(255, 255, 255);
```

Comment: Downvote - 'System.Drawing.Color' does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments